# What is the `imrect` equivalent in Python?

Tags: python

I'm looking for a simple Python utility or module that:

- I can give it an image, and it pops up a GUI window for the user to draw a box inside the image
- after drawing the box, it returns the coordinates of the box

MATLAB users will realize that I am asking for [`imrect`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imrect.html) equivalent in Python.

Is there a simple utility out there to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick implementation, for any future searchers: https://raw.github.com/cvondrick/pyvision/master/vision/drawer.py

Comment: With your code, should the following work? im = Image.open('f1.png');  Drawer(im)

Answer (score 2):

You can try [`PIL`](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) - Python Imaging Library.

For GUI there's a module named [`tkinter`](http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/), though there may be some better options too.

Comment: [tkdocs tutorial](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/index.html) might be a better starting point for [`Tkinter`](http://docs.python.org/library/tkinter.html)

Comment: yep - I'm very familiar with PIL and Tkinter, but I'd rather just use an existing utility. Perhaps I just need to stop being lazy and write one myself.

Answer (score 1):

Since most people coming to Python from MATLAB will be making use of lots of [SciPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciPy), [NumPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy), and [Matplotlib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matplotlib) functions, I would think that the **RectangleSelector function of Matplotlib** would be the closest equivalent to the [imrect](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imrect.html) function in MATLAB. It is probably a little easier to implement than the other examples if you are already making your plots using Matplotlib.

See this example: *[Widgets example code: rectangle_selector.py](http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/rectangle_selector.html)*

And this page: *[class matplotlib.widgets.RectangleSelector](http://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.RectangleSelector)*

Note: Mac users will need to switch renderers to get this example to work, by including the following code:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
```

Here is that example in action:

[image]

Unlike the imrect function in MATLAB, the default behavior is for the box to only stay in place while you are drawing it.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [OpenCV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV)'s Python implementation! It is fast and is integrated with [PyQt 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyQt)!

[OpenCV Homepage](http://opencv.org/)

Comment: How is this better than the other answers?